# What does the below script do

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I would really appreciate if some one can explain the below code.

```
echo "Starting" '\n'

name=$1 firstfilter="{\"root\":\"$2\",\"rules\":[]}"

for i in "${@:3}"; do TEMP=",{\"root\":\"$i\",\"rules\":[]}" PATH1+="$TEMP" done
```

Comment: It generates something that sort of looks like JSON, but isn't.

Comment: I think there's a missing "done"

Comment: "Explain this code" doesn't make it *at all* clear exactly what you don't understand, so an answer has to cover far more depth than would be needed if one extracted out an individual piece and constructed a well-asked question around same.

Comment: Mainly trying to understand what this piece of code is doing in the for loop "${@:3}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is indeed generating JSON, but in fact its structure is a bit weird.

> If what you are asking is the `"${@:3}"` part; it accepts all
>   arguments after the third one (including the third one)

### Solution

This is the result after I refactored your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NAME="${1}"
PATH1=
for ARG in "${@:2}"
do
  PATH1+="{\"root\":\"${ARG}\",\"rules\":[]},"
done
PATH1=$(sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /' <<< "${PATH1}")

echo -e "${NAME}\n${PATH1}"
```

I used the `sed` command to remove the last comma from the JSON sequences.

### Input & Output

```
$ bash a.sh "this is a name" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
Starting

this is a name
{"root":"a","rules":[]},{"root":"b","rules":[]},{"root":"c","rules":[]},{"root":"d","rules":[]},{"root":"e","rules":[]},{"root":"f","rules":[]},{"root":"g","rules":[]}
```

### Usage

Assuming that your script's filename is `mkjson.sh`

```
 bash mkjson.sh "first" "second" "third" "fourth" "fifth"
```

### Explanation

- The argument "first" is for the variable "name"
- All the arguments from "second" to "fifth" are used as values for the key "root". The number of JSON sequences is defined of how many arguments are passed.

  - For two arguments, one JSON sequence will be generated
  - For three arguments, two JSON sequences will be generated
  - For N arguments, N-1 JSON sequences will be generated